# To require or not to require { model, Schema } for mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, syntax, require

Is there any difference between requiring twice as opposed to just destructuring `model` and `Schema` from the existing variable `mongoose` already created?

Here are the two different examples. In a Node app is there a difference between the two following code examples outside of basic syntax and readability.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { model, Schema } = mongoose;
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose')
```

It seems they both work fine. I assume it's a very simple question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `mongoose` object later, then go with the first one. If you want to use only `model` and `Schema` then go simply with:

```
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose')
```

You don't want to load the module twice, there is a performance difference.

Comment: So in summary can you just elaborate on the 2nd example. Is that something you simply never want to do? And any possibility you could explain more on the performance hit maybe in a larger application or at scale? It's really never a good idea to re-require right?

Comment: The performance hit is not significant, but it exists. Here you can check out that the module gets evaluated only once and reference equality is kept: https://repl.it/@ukaszKarczewski/KindheartedDopeyDeeplearning , so re-requiring things is really redundant and introduces mess into your application.